# Logic behind $n\geq 4\epsilon$ if $n!$ ends in $\epsilon$ zeroes

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I ran into a question in my book, **Find $n$ such that $n!$ ends in $12$ zeroes**. This can be done with guessing a value of $n$ and improving estimates at each stage until finally being able to judge the exact values of $n$.

They, however,  start in the book with the proposition that **if $n!$ ends in $\epsilon$ zeroes then $n\geq 4\epsilon$**.

Instead of the proof, I'd like to know why it's obvious and why it makes sense. I'm comfortable with the basics of combinatorics if that'll come into use. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the factorization of $n!$, $5$'s are less plentiful then $2$'s, so the number of zeroes is just the number of $5$'s. There are $\lfloor n/5\rfloor$ multiples of $5$ which are less than $n$. In addition, the $\lfloor n/25\rfloor$ multiples of $25$ in $n!$ contribute an extra $5$ each. Same for the multiples of $5^3=125$, and of $5^4=625$, and so on. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\text{# zeroes}
  &=\lfloor n/5\rfloor+\lfloor n/5^2\rfloor+\lfloor n/5^3\rfloor+\dots
\\&\le n/5+n/5^2+n/5^3+\dots
\\&=\frac{n/5}{1-1/5}
\\&=n/4.
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\text{# zeroes}=\epsilon$, we have $n\ge 4\epsilon$.